# Как задать alias, если у нас есть два подлюченных файла, где объекты с одинаковым именем?

Tags: javascript

Есть два подлючаемых js-файла, каждый из которых содержит свой объект, но при этом имена у них одинаковые.

Когда я их подключаю на странице и создают экземпляр, то создаст потомка первого подлюченного файла.

Мне на странице нужно оперировать двуме разными объектами. Имена поменять не могу.

```js
// path_to_script/obj1.js
var TestObject = function() {
  // some code
}

// path_to_script/obj2.js
var TestObject = function() {
  // some code
}

<script src="path_to_script/obj1.js"></script>
<script src="path_to_script/obj2.js"></script>

<script>
  var objectOne = new TestObject();
  var objectTwo = new TestObject();
</script>
```

Comment: добавь [mcve]. Пример содержимого файлов, как их подключаешь и как используешь

Comment: Вот, вставил пример кода. Суть изложил в самом посте.